# Private Objects and Lists

Tags: java, private, instantiation, encapsulation

Why are the encapsulation of an instantiated object never defined?

```
Duck duck = new Duck();
```

Wouldn't this set all objects to default per definition and thereby accessible everywhere?

Moreover, is there a reason why Lists aren't usually set private when instantiated?

```
List<Ducks> ducks = new ArrayList<>();
```

I understand your critique, i do understand what encapsulation is. 
I have to present a huge website tomorrow in front of 3 teachers and wondered why we have all other attributes set to private when the instantiated lists / objects encapsulations are never defined. Thanks for any serious answer

```
Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
```

For example these three objects from the java tutorial. Their encapsulation (private/public/protected) are never stated

Comment: ... who says they are not?

Comment: Do you know what "private" means in Java? Doesn't look like it, thus can you explain what you think it means?

Comment: No i mean, usually when objects are instantiated, the encapsulation is never defined aka its set to public, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Do you have any real examples of what you're talking about? What code are you looking at where access modifiers are not being used?

Comment: `Why are instantiated objects never set to private?` what do you mean? we can set .

Comment: I know, we can set it.. thats not the point. The point i'm asking and the essence of the question is, why isn't it ever set, in any tutorials or any application i've ever seen.

Comment: If for instance an object is instantiated as stated above, would this mean that methods from this class could potentially be called from all classes, now that the instantiated object is public?

Comment: Maybe the code your looking at is bad code. Or maybe there is some context to it that means that it doesn't require an access modifier. Or maybe it's a simple tutorial that is trying not to overcomplicate things. We can't tell because __we don't know what code you are looking at__.

Comment: Well then take a look at the god damn java tutorials

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: not a single encapsulation on those instantiated objects

Comment: Everywhere in that example that is declaring an instance field, it has an access modifier. In isolated lines with no context, there is no access modifier because they're not declaring fields: they're just showing in general how to instantiate an object.

Comment: I'm still not talking about instance fields, im talking about instantiating objects

Comment: Look latest edit

Comment: All these "examples" in the question are meaningless when you don't say where the variables are declared. "im talking about instantiating objects" then you really don't know what `private` means. An object doesn't has and doesn't need access modifiers.

Comment: Access modifiers only make sense in certain context (e.g. instance fields). In other places they would serve no purpose and are not allowed. Without context, it makes no sense to expect a variable to have an access modifier.

Comment: perfect! Tom that's the answer i was looking for, THANK YOU

Comment: It doesn't need access modifiers, great :D so in my class diagram when i write an object in the attributes field i wont make a - or a +, thanks

Comment: _An object_ doesn't need access modifiers, but a variable can has an access modifier, depending on where it is declared. Thus if you have a question regarding such variables, then you need to tell us where these variables are declared.

Comment: @ITGuru read my answer again. it depends on if the variable is and instance variable or a local method variable.

Comment: Allright, no i got how variables are accessed, i was just wondering about the object part, thanks

Comment: Jack i know method variables are local and instance variables are global thanks alot. I was wondering about the objects part

Answer (score 2):

only instance (and static class variables) variables can be private (well methods and classes too), and you set them to private yourself.

```
public class Pond {
    private Duck duck;
}
```

access modifiers are not used in methods, only on fields because a variable declared in a method is only used and accessible in that method.

If you have instance variable like in the code above the visibility of it depends on the modifier. `public` means that anyone can access it it and so on: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i wasn't wondering about encapsulation on simple attributes though :) I was wondering if an instantiated object is accessible everywhere if the encapsulation is never stated.

Comment: Perfect, so if i instantiate an object in one class, without declaring it private, it cant be reached from another class right? :) that's really just the only thing in fishing for here

Comment: @ITGuru no if you would have just written `Duck duck` it means the default modifier and anyone in the same package can access it. read up on the modifiers and you will understand

Comment: but i didn't write Duck duck, i wrote Duck duck = new Duck();

Comment: @ITGuru I was talking about instance variables. If you are talkinng about local variables in a method you do not use modifiers bacause of the reasons mentioned. modifiers are set when you declare, whether you instantiate them or not.